# Bug datepicker field when more than one on contribution page

Tags: fields, jquery

I have civicrm installed on wordpress
I have a issue with datepicker field
When i put only one datepicker field it's works well
But if i insert more than one datepicker field in a form, the datepicker field are breaked.
I have try with a fresh install on new versions of civicrm and wordpress and i have the same problem.

Could you help me to solve this issue

Thanks !

Comment: Please give more information. Describe how they are broken. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i don't have see you answer. The datefield are display with two fields and the calendar icon just after

Answer (score -1):

[image: datepicker fiel bu when two datepicker on one form]

Hello you can see here the way my datepicker field are displayed when two are on the same form.

This bug is also present with a fresh install

Thanks for help

Comment: Thanks for providing more information but you should do this by editing your original question rather than posting this as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have found
This is a civcrm bug when you specify a range of year in custom datefield, the field is broken